When will the useLayoutEffect hook callback be triggered?
I have an question about when will the useLayoutEffect callback be triggered and when will the screen be drawn.
Consider the following code:
export default function CompA() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    // I'll debug here after initial render 
    console.log('CompA layoutEffectCallback');
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('CompA updateEffectCallback');
  }, [count]);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setCount(count + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div onClick={handleClick}>
      CompA
      <h1>{count}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

After the initial render, the screen displays the number 0,then I set a chrome devtool debugger in the callback of the useLayoutEffect hook before I click the div. After click, the function execution is paused at debugger, but I see the screen already shown number 1.
The docs said that useLayoutEffect fires before the browser repaints the screen，but I don't understand why the screen has updated.


In case you missed it, or haven't taken the full [tour] yet (you earn a badge BTW), there are 100% completely optional actions one can take after someone answers that helps rate and curate content on the site.

Pausing/break-pointing in the useLayoutEffect callback doesn't prevent/block the browser from repainting. It's merely a place you can "hook" into and apply some logic like measuring the computed DOM before the browser repaints. You will still see the updated DOM and repainted view regardless.
Here's a handy, albeit a bit outdated, diagram of the React component lifecycle:

useLayoutEffect is called in roughly the "pre-commit phase" where it can check the computed DOM. useEffect would be called later/after the "commit phase".

tks very much,could you please explain more about "Pausing/break-pointing in the useLayoutEffect callback doesn't prevent/block the browser",I don't really understand about that

@ecnatsiDehTog Sure. It might help you to think of these effects as sort of React lifecycle "event listeners", wherein a mounting or rerender "event" occurred and was processed, and these hooks allow you to "listen" and "react" to the "event", but breaking in the callback doesn't block/prevent the rest of the entire app from continuing on. The event happened and React is processing it to completion, which means computing/diffing the DOM and rerendering. You'd need to set breakpoints in the actual React framework code if you wanted to stop it. Does this make sense?

yep,there are lot of article describing useLayoutEffect as synchronous code and useLayoutEffect blocks browser rendering,speechless.....

@ecnatsiDehTog The useLayoutEffect callback is synchronous, yes, but I don't see how it could possibly block browser rendering. Like I said, I think you'd need to set a breakpoint in the actual React code handling the lifecycles and DOM updates to really block anything.

yes ,and I'll try the example in react document and set some breakpoint in the actual React code,thank you for your help

@ecnatsiDehTog Actually it is interesting behavior if you add code let k = 1;      for (let i = 0; i < 9000000000; i++) k *= 9; inside useLayoutEffect you will see it will take a while before it displays 1 on the screen after you click 0. The same behavior doesn't happen with debugger though.

@DrewReese If I put debugger inside render instead of useLayoutEffect then it does block the repaint. It is an interesting difference.

The useLayoutEffect hook runs synchronously after the DOM is updated but before the browser repaints.
Initially, you rendered CompA, and the initial state of count was 0. Then, you clicked the div and count was increased to 1.
Since useLayoutEffect is ran after the DOM has been updated BUT before it repaints, the layout effect will log CompA layoutEffectCallback right before the browser performs the paint. This is why you see the screen showing "1" even when the debugger is paused in useLayoutEffect. The DOM has already been updated with the new state before the browser is notified to render it.

so what's the different between DOM updated  and repaints?I thought that dom is an object , we update the object in memory then browser render to screen.it's sounds like there are two phase and the useLayoutEffect will be invoked between them.so why the screen showing "1" when the debugger is paused in useLayoutEffect.I'm still puzzled
